# Cleaner way of splitting DFs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine you have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"VATcheck": [True, False], "taxrate#1": [True, False]})
```

I want to seperate the df based on each column value is true or false:

```
dffinalselection = dffinal.loc[~df['taxrate#1']] 
dfresult_secondlook55    = dffinal.loc[df['taxrate#1']]

dfresult_secondlook53 = dffinal.loc[~dffinal['VATcheck']]
dfresult_secondlook54   = dffinal.loc[dffinal['VATcheck']]
```

However, now I have 4 dfs which I have to merge/join again, which becomes very painful when performing multiple checks...

Is there a cleaner/faster way of putting in multiple conditions?

My goal is to have two seperate dataframes: one that only have True values and one only having False values (based on the two conditions).

Please help!

Comment: Is your goal to identify the rows of your dataframe having each combination of the possible column values? For example here, flag them with `('TT', 'FF', 'FT', 'TF')`?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. My goal is to have two seperate dataframes: one that only have True values and one only having False values.

Comment: How would you proceed Guillaume? Best, Max

Comment: Do you need to make it work for any number of columns or just these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df_true = df[df['VATcheck'] & df['taxrate#1']]
df_false = df[~df['VATcheck'] & ~df['taxrate#1']]
```

(In this specific case you don't need to put parentheses around each condition because they are unary boolean operators. With other operators like `==`, you would need parentheses, like: `df[(df['VATcheck'] == True) & (df['taxrate#1'] == True)]`)

And for any number of columns:

```py
df_true = df[df.all(axis=1)]
df_false = df[~df.any(axis=1)]
```

See pandas documentation for [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html).

Comment: This works. I just want to mention that the brackets enclosing the conditions are important. If not it will throw an error.

Comment: @ThilinaDissanayake actually in this case parentheses are not needed (unary operators around the `&`), so I removed them and added an example where they would be necessary. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Are your values all boolean `True` or `False`?

Comment: It worked! Did some things wrong. Thank you @GuillaumeAnsanay-Alex